Is using SQS Lambda combination the only way here?
I have a architectural problem at work,
There are records coming into a SNS FIFO topic, each record coming in needs to be processed by 3 different modules in a sequential manner.
For sake of simplicity let's assume the modules are Lambda A, B, C.
Strict requirement

Ensure the messages with same grouping ID in SNS FIFO are processed in order
Ensure that for messages with same grouping ID in SNS FIFO, the new message is not processed until the previous one is finished (SUCCESSFUL or FAILED).


The Most obvious way to do it is to choreograph using SQS FIFO in between Lambda A,B,C
Record -> SNS FIFO -> SQS FIFO -> Lambda A -> SQS FIFO -> Lambda B -> SQS FIFO -> Lambda C

This will make debugging the failure points for a single record really tough, not impossible but a bit time consuming.
Another approach I was thinking was since these 3 Lambda's need to be executed in a sequence and are related, why not use orchestration instead using Step Functions (SF).
Record -> SNS FIFO -> SQS FIFO -> SF Invoke Lambda -> SF (Lambda A -> Lambda B -> Lambda C)

The problem here would be that SF Invoke Lambda will fire and forget SF for each message in a group ID and this will break the 2nd strict requirement.
A way around that would be to check whether the previous SF has completed execution before invoking a new execution of SF for the next message in SF Invoke Lambda. This will be done by checking the process_state of each execution in a DB, and Lambda C would be responsible for updating it to "SUCCESS/FAILED" state.
Record -> SNS FIFO -> SQS FIFO -> SF Invoke Lambda -> SF (Lambda A -> Lambda B -> Lambda C -> Update DB)
                               -> SF Invoke Lambda -> Check DB for process_state -> SF (Lambda A -> Lambda B -> Lambda C -> Update DB)

Questions:

What are some outright downsides of approach 1? Is that too many staging layers?
Is this way around really better than the simpler approach 1?
Is this not a use-case for orchestration?
Should we let Lambda invoke Step Functions for incoming records but have a initial "Wait for previous SF completion" state?
Another thing to keep in mind, there might be more modules in the future that might need to be included in the processing flow. Step Functions would be easily extendible but with first solution it might involve another SQS FIFO.
Any other completely different approach which I am totally missing?


This is how I do if I were you,

Record -> SNS FIFO Queue -> SQS FIFO Queue

Then use Lambda(A) to Poll the queue 1 message per polling
a. Keep a track of that message using the unique value from the message(If you have any) or create hash of the message and store in DynamoDB or Redis or any other database. Do this in Lambda(A)
b. Do whatever processing you plan to do in Lambda A and B and C
c. Before exiting the Lambda(C) update the statues in the DB for that particular message(Dynamo, Redis or any db you use).
d. Before polling the next message in the Lambda(A), check whether you have anything that is still being processed by checking (Dynamo, Redis or any db you use) where you store the reference of the currently processing item. If the existing message haven't completed then skip the execution.


Schedule the Lambda A in a EventRule to trigger every 5 minutes are so, based on your preference.
If you prefer you can also store the status of each Lambda in the database like this [message, Lambda A Result, Lambda B Result, Lambda C Result, Final Status]. It will make the debugging easier too

Thanks for your response, but i don't agree with your approach because it is not real time processing if i have to schedule polling of Lambda A. I think i should have mentioned that in the requirements (my bad). Also you didn't state how will Lambda A pass request to B and C. That is the main crux of my problem here whether to use staging in between or orchestration, since orchestration will give me flexibility moving forward but directly doesn't support my  strict requirement 2. If you have any other insights, please do share

There are multiple ways to pass the request from one to another, you can just invoke the Lambda B from Lambda A and invoke Lambda C from Lambda B or you can pass the message an SQS FIFO queue and subscribe from it

You can use temporal.io for this. You can write code like:
@WorkflowInterface
public interface SerializedExecutionWorkflow {

    @WorkflowMethod
    void execute();

    @SignalMethod
    void addTask(Task t);
}

@ActivityInterface
public interface TaskProcessorActivity {
    void process(Task poll);
}

public class SerializedExecutionWorkflowImpl implements SerializedExecutionWorkflow {

    private final Queue<Task> taskQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final TaskProcesorActivities activities = Workflow.newActivityStub(TaskProcesorActivities.class);

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        while(!taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Task task = taskQueue.poll();
            activities.a(...);
            activities.b(...);
            activities.c(...);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addTask(Task t) {
        taskQueue.add(t);
    }
}

And then the SNS FIFO Listener calls the following function:
private void addTask(WorkflowClient cadenceClient, Task task) {
    // Set workflowId to userId
    WorkflowOptions options = WorkflowOptions.newBuilder()
       .setTaskQueue(TASK_QUEUE)
       .setWorkflowId(task.getGroupingId())
       .build();
    // Use workflow interface stub to start/signal workflow instance
    SerializedExecutionWorkflow workflow = temporalClient.newWorkflowStub(SerializedExecutionWorkflow.class, options);
    BatchRequest request = temporalClient.newSignalWithStartRequest();
    request.add(workflow::execute);
    request.add(workflow::addTask, task);
    temporalClient.signalWithStart(request);
}

If you use this approach then you don't need the incoming SNS queue. The limitation that this works well with the large number of groups and doesn't work well if each group get a high update rate.
